# To print the environment from the stdin (var name) & execute the getenv() function it compiles correctly but no output what am i missing?

Tags: c, getenv

```
int main(int ac, char **av, char **env) 
{
    unsigned int i = 1;
    while(getenv("env[i]") != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", env[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int i = 0; while(env[i] != NULL) { ... }`

Comment: The argument to `getenv` is the name of an environment variable. If you give it something which is not the name of an environment variable, it returns NULL.

Comment: Array indexes start at `0`, not `1`.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed above, arrays start at index 0 and the loop condition is wrong (`"env[i]"` is a fixed string, also `getenv()` takes a `name` but `env[i]` is a `name=value` pair):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int ac, char **av, char **env) {
    for(unsigned i = 0; env[i]; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", env[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yhaa that i did that but i want to insert the var name manually and printout that specific value for the name I inserted how should I proceed

Comment: That is an entirely different question.  If you have the name, say, "PATH", then you call getenv("PATH").  If you don't have the name, then you need to extract it from `env[i]` for example `char *end = index(env[i], '='); if(!end) { ...}; char *name = strndup(env[i], end - env[i] + 1); name[end - env[i]] = '\0'; getenv(name); free(name);`